# which unit-test framework for PHP: simpletest, phpunit or?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, simpletest

I'm a big fan of [simpletest](http://www.simpletest.org/) because it's what I know. It has excellent support for mocking and web-testing.

But I'm always scared of stagnating so any compelling arguments to switch would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think either is going away anytime soon. Simpletest is maintained by a small, but involved group of people.

PHPUnit seems to have a bigger userbase, which may count as an argument for switching. I'm quite happy with Simpletest though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used SimpleTest myself, so I can't say much in a way of comparison. Just by observation though, the PHPUnit syntax seems much more verbose.

The [PHPUnit Manual](http://www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.3/en/index.html) is a great source of documentation, and covers most areas of the framework. My only complaint about the manual is that some areas lack detail.

My main reason for using PHPUnit over SimpleTest is that it has great [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) integration.

Comment: SimpleTest 1.0.1 beta+ seems supported by Phing 2.3.x as per their user guide: http://phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/Setup.html#SystemRequirements.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282150/how-do-i-write-unit-tests-in-php) and added that there's [phpt](http://qa.php.net/write-test.php). phpt also integrates into PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend behat (+mink)
http://behat.org/

It's functional/integrational testing, but it covers much more code in much less time...

P.S. You can, actually, use it to write unit/tests, but it's a bit of overkill...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd want to switch per-se, but I like *phpt* for testing small libraries of code or getting tests out the door sooner rather than later, if there are none in an existing library that needs to be tested.

*phpt* won't scale as well as Simpletest, but again, the right tool for the right job. Take a look at [this article](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/10/practical-phpt/) for an in-depth discussion to get you ramped up.